# Dropdownfor selected item changes after ModelState is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I send my view model with POST to my controller (with no city selected) I get an expected "required city" error but when I select a city (say first in list) and then I have another error (for example first name is missing) so my model state is still not valid it redirects me to the initial page and selects suddenly some city from the bottom (or random at times)

In the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, Model.SelectListCities, "Select City", new { @class = "form-control", @name = "City" })
```

In the controller

```
 public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        RegisteredVisitorVM Model = new RegisteredVisitorVM();

        List<City> cities = principal.Cities.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> cityList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        cityList.AddRange(cities.Select(
                x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.CountryID.ToString(), Text = x.Name }
            ).ToList()
        );

        Model.SelectListCities = cityList;
        return View("RegistrationView", Model);
    }
    public ActionResult SubmitRegisteredVisitors(RegisteredVisitorVM model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> cityList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<City> cities = principal.Cities.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

            cityList.AddRange(cities.Select(
                    x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.CountryID.ToString(), Text = x.Name }
                ).ToList()
            );

            model.SelectListCities = cityList;
            return View("RegistrationView", model);
        }

        return Content(model.FirstName);
    }
```

In the ViewModel

```
using CondorExtreme3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CondorExtreme3.Areas.Users.Models
{
    public class RegisteredVisitorVM
    {
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name is too long!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required!")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Username is too long!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required!")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Password is too long!")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Must have at least 8 characters!")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{2,}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be alpha-numeric!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required!")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required!")]
    [RegularExpression("^[^@]+@[^@]+\\.[^@]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required!")]
    public int CityID{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectListCities { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: try adding cityList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem{Value ="", Text = "Select City"}); before you set the SelectListCities propety on the model

Comment: I tried but that just leads to "Selected City" being displayed two times (once in the view once in the controller)

Comment: @Ilhan can i see the code for `RegisteredVisitorVM`

Comment: I edited the view model code in @CodingYoshi

Comment: @Ilhan when you select an item and your model is not valid, can you check if your model has that `CityID` which you selected in it?

Comment: @CodingYoshi By sheer accident I checked that actually this moment before you posted.. the CityID it sends in (when my model is valid) is always either 10 or 11 or 12 (corresponding to the cities it selects when I return back to the view)

Comment: No I want you to check the value when the model is NOT valid

Comment: When the model is not valid, I get the wrong CityID still (same as if it is valid), always 10 11 or 12 that is @CodingYoshi

Comment: Do you have any javascript doing something in your view?

Comment: only included bootstrap and jquery.. nothing custom or used explicitly

Comment: Show us your view and the POST action. If you don't mark your action `HttpPost` it will be a GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej Ilhan, 
I had this exact problem when I was creating some seminar work for college.

First time I wasn't re-populating list when validation fails, and second time is when inteli sense was creating issue, which I resolved only after restarting VS.
So in short, if you are using Code First are you sure that var name is "CountryID" and not "CountryId"? :D